# Extreme oscillations and values in heat equation on a 1D closed ring

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations, stability, models

I am trying to create a (very) simple model of heat diffusion along a closed rod (e.g., a ring) with an initial condition in which one segment is hotter than the rest.

I'm using the following formula:

$$T_x^{t+1} = T_x^{t} + \Delta t \alpha \frac{T_{x-1}^{t} + T_{x-1}^{t} - 2 T_{x1}^{t}}{(\Delta x)^2} $$

with $T$ being temperature, $x$ position, and $\alpha = \frac{\lambda}{\rho c}$ being the transmission coefficient given by heat conductivity $\lambda$, density $\rho$ and thermal capacity $c$.

I noticed that when $\alpha$ get close to one the system become unstable, with growing oscillations that produce extreme temperatures above and below the initial temperature range.

Here is the R code of a simulation for a 100 segment long rod with one segment at 10°C and the rest at 1°C. The alpha is set to have a thermal conductivity of one-tenth of $\rho c$. This setting does not produce instability and the results seem realistic:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    
        v <- c(rep(1, 49), 10, rep(1, 50))
        
        out <- data.frame()
        
        for (i in 1:20) {
            d2T <- c(v[2:length(v)], v[1]) + c(v[length(v)], v[1:(length(v) - 1)]) - 2 * v
            
            # dx = dt = 1
            d2X <- 1
            dT <- 1
            
            out <- bind_rows(out, data.frame(
                val = v,
                x = 1:length(v),
                grad = d2T,
                iter = i
            ))

            v <- v + .1 * d2T/d2X
            
        }
        
        
        print(ggplot(out, aes(x, val)) +
            geom_line(alpha = .5, show.legend = F) +
            geom_point(aes(color = grad)) +
            scale_color_viridis_c(option = 'A') +
            facet_wrap(~ iter) +
            theme_minimal()) +
            labs(x = 'x', y = 'T', color = 'd2T/d2x')
```

[image]

But if $\alpha$ is set to .5 or more we observed unstable trends.

[image]

The model becomes totally unrealistic as $\alpha$ gets close to 1, with values well beyond the initial temperature range of 1-10°C. This is $\alpha = .9$:

[image]

I guess that either I messed up the model, or it's a side effect of poor discretization of a continuous process. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong.  The explicit scheme is unstable at values higher than 2.  To make your problem go away,, you need to switch to a time implicit scheme like backward Euler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Von Neumann or Fourier stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) fails for the [explicit finite difference scheme in this context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Example:_The_heat_equation). The time step $\Delta t$ must be smaller than $(\Delta x)^2/2\alpha$ to suppress instabilities, where $\Delta x$ corresponds to the spatial discretization and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity. This is why time and distance steps of unity tend to fail with $\alpha \ge 0.5$.

If you are constrained in this aspect, consider using an implicit finite difference solution method, which is always stable (but more computationally intensive).

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea! if you by chance have any reference about an implemented solution I'd be grateful, otherwise I'll see what I find!

Comment: even better if there is an exact solution

Comment: Perhaps Crank’s *Mathematics of Diffusion*.

Comment: While searching for more appropriate solutions, I patched the model in order to forbid $dT/dt$ larger than $(T_{x-1} + T_x + T_{x + 1}) / 3$, that is the temperature in one segment cannot go beyond the mean temperature in its triplet of segments. This stabilizes the dynamics, removing both oscillations and extreme values. I know it's a hack but I was wondering if it approximates some more general principia (or it's really just an ugly hack).

Comment: sorry, I meant a $dT/dt$ larger than $T_x - (T_{x-1} + T_x + T_{x+1})/3$ in absolute value